# How do I force creation of the Winform handle in C#

Tags: c#, .net, invoke, handle

I am getting the following runtime error message

> Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

Here is what I think is going on.  My winform constructor is creating some objects, one of which received asynchronous TCP/IP data.  To make a long story short, I have event delegates which allow the class receiving the network data to call a routine from the Winform to print the data to a text box.  This is so I can see what was received.  I can see that data is immediately received.  This happens before the winform constructor has finished.

I read around and you cannot invoke a winform or winform component until its handle has been created.  I suspect this is what I am violating.  Supposedly there is a function to force this.  I tried adding the following code to my winform constructor to force the creation before I create my class receiving TCP/IP data.  However, the error remains.

```
InitializeComponent();
this.CreateControl();
this.HistoryBox.CreateControl();
```

Here is the code for my winform delegate in case it helps:

```
    public void Print_Console_Message(string message)
    {
        Console_Output.Enqueue(message);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(PrintToConsole));
    }
    private void PrintToConsole(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = Console_Output.Dequeue();

        if (message.Length != 0)
        {
            HistoryBox.AppendText(message + "\n" + "\n");
        }
    }
```

I realize there is a way to check object handle was created and avoid the call in that case, however, I am not interested in simply inhibiting some of the output.

Does anyone know how I can force the handle or control creation so that the delegate functions could be called before the constructor is finished?

Comment: Can you move the creation of the object that requires a invoke to the [`Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead of the constructor? The `Load` event fires after the handle has been created and is good for situations like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) you can do this by getting the `.Handle` property.

> If the handle has not yet been created, referencing this property will force the handle to be created.

Alternatively, you could listen for the `HandleCreated` event and only `Invoke` after it's fired.

Comment: ok that did the trick.  Here is what it looked like for me:          
            `if (this.Handle != null && this.HistoryBox.Handle != null && this.Error_Output != null && this.Dev_Output_Window != null)
            { }`

Comment: The `.Handle` property will throw the `InvalidOperationException` if uiElement.`InvokeRequired == true`. Better to use uiElement.`CreateControl()`; method. It's indifferent to code modifications.

Comment: If `InvokeRequired` was `true` then I would expect the same exception to be thrown when calling a method.  `CreateControl()` does read a bit better but it's not guaranteed to create the handle.